# How to avoid values not to display with the url while using window.location.href to pass values from one page to other?

Tags: javascript, html

In my localhost url, am getting all the values which is being passed to the other page are getting displayed in the url.

I dont want it to display the values which are passing,

for example

```
http://localhost/accounting/credit/credit.php?prod=sdfsdfsd-12&prodId=6&batch=567567
```

am using window.location.href to pass the values to other page, i think that is the reason its getting added to the url. Is there any other way to pass the values other than window.location.href ? or is there any other way to pass.

Is it possible to make the url not to display the values ?

I just want the url to display as below

```
http://localhost/accounting/medismo/credit_note/credit.php
```

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this pretty simply using jQuery and an HTTP request:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'credit.php',
   type: 'POST',
   data: { prod: 'sdfsdf-12', prodID: 6 },
   success: function (data, status) {
       // Handle successful request
   },
   error: function (xhr, status, err) {
       // Handle request failure
   }
});
```

In this case, data is an object containing all the information you want to pass over to the given url.  In your .php file you can access this information using:

```
$_POST["prod"], $_POST["prodID"], etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

The tool you are using is called the GET-method to pass variables trough a URI! Another method you can use is the POST-method, which uses html forms (still visible in the source code). 
For information about those two HTTP request methods, look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GET_%28HTTP%29#Request_methods) or use Google!

The next best method would be using a [php session](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php), where (when used properly) users won't be able to see the variables directly!